# git как удалить файлы из репозитория, когда в папке на компьютере их нету, а на гитхабе почему-то есть

Tags: git, github

В созданной папке репозитория на компьютере этих файлов нету, а на github есть почему-то. Как обновить репозиторий, чтобы и на github было тоже самое, что и в моей папке, чтобы удалились файлы из репозитория которых в моей папке нету

Может обновить как-то?

Comment: Чей репозиторий? Как создавалась папка на компьютере?

Comment: удали эти файлы на самом гитхабе и выполни команду `git pull`, должно сработать

Comment: Варианты почему так может быть: локальные файлы не добавлены в отслеживаемые(`git add`), файлы находятся в игнроре(файл `.gitignore`)

Answer (score -1):

Смотрите, я на Ваш вопрос отвечу в три шага.

1. Как сделать, чтобы на гитхабе было то же самое, что и в локальной папке (короткий ответ):

клонируем репозиторий к себе:

```
    git clone git@github.com:mynick/myrepo.git
```

При этом репозиторий клонируется в *отдельную* папку. Которой на компьютере раньше не было.

Удаляем локально файлы, котрых быть не должно.

делаем коммит и пуш:

```
    git commit -m "some files deleted"
    git push
```

Гит может попросить подсказок насчет того, в какую ветку пушить и т.п., но в общем - последовательность действий именно такая.

В результате, в на гитхабе *после* Вашего коммита этих файлов не будет

Обратите внимание, файлов нет в *последнем* коммите. В истории гита эти файлы остались.

2. Представим себе, что Вы случайно положили в гит файлики, которых там вообще не должно быть. Даже в истории. Ну, какие нибудь приватные ключики или файлы с паролями. И нужно в публичном репозитории убрать это *в том числе из истории*.

Тогда надо делать по другому. Нужно "переписать историю", лежащую в гит.

Если у Вас проблема "файл, которого не должно быть, лежит в последнем коммите" - то Вам нужен ключик `--amend` в команде `git commit --amend`

Если же файл успел "уйти в историю" - то понадобится `rebase`. Эта тема чуть чуть сложнее, и я советую прочесть [документацию](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)

3. Почему вообще так? Почему нельзя задним числом удалить файл, не трогая "более поздних" коммитов?

Это происходит потому, что "подпись" коммита - это хеш от всех файлов, входящих в коммит, к тому же захешированный с предыдущим хешом. Поэтому нельзя что то поменять "задним числом": в результате хеши перестанут сходиться. Такй себе "натуральный блокчейн"

Comment: Это не помогло :(
Хоть он и написал: "Everything up-to-date"
Но ничего не изменилось

Comment: А репозиторий публичный? Просто, можно глазаи посмотерть на те файлы, которых не должно быть? может, что то придёт в голову?

Comment: Репозиторий публичный

Comment: Может, добавите его в Ваш вопрос? И каких файлов там не должно быть - тоже?